# Why is $\bar\phi(-k) = \bar\phi ^*(k)$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, field-theory, fourier-transform, complex-numbers

In Peskin and Schroeder chapter 2 p. 20, they claim that for a real field $\phi(x)$, its Fourier transform $\bar{\phi}(k)$ obey
$$\bar{\phi}(-k) = \bar{\phi}^*(k)$$

I am confused as to why this is true and how it preserves that $ \phi(x) $ is real valued.
$\phi(x) = \phi^* (x)$, so shouldn't it also follow that $\bar{\phi}(k) = \bar{\phi}^*(k)$ ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with QFT. Consider any (real) function and its Fourier transform...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will write the proof in one-dimension, but it generalizes to other dimensions in a straightforward manner. Let us write
$$\phi(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \tilde{\phi}(k) e^{i k x} \mathrm{d}k. \tag{1}$$

Notice that
\begin{align}
\phi^*(x) &= \left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \tilde{\phi}(k) e^{i k x} \mathrm{d}k \right)^*, \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \tilde{\phi}^*(k) e^{-i k x} \mathrm{d}k, \\
&= - \int_{+\infty}^{-\infty} \tilde{\phi}^*(-k) e^{i k x} \mathrm{d}k, \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \tilde{\phi}^*(-k) e^{i k x} \mathrm{d}k. \tag{2}
\end{align}

From (1), (2), and $\phi(x) = \phi^*(x)$ we find $\tilde{\phi}(k) = \tilde{\phi}^*(-k)$.

Comment: I do have an issue here however, just because two integrals are equal **does not** mean that the integrands are also equal. Why can you assume here that they are given that we showed the two integrals are equal only for the specific bounds $(-\infty,\infty)$ and not for any bounds ?

Comment: @realanswers Your point is correct, but the theorems on uniqueness of Fourier transforms/inverses are enough to get to the conclusion.

Comment: @NíckolasAlves I think it was better to start with the Fourier transform itself rather than the inverse

Answer (score 1):

As Tobias wrote in the comment, it has nothing to do with QFT.
It follows immediately from the definition of Fourier transform: plug in $-k$ to the transform, you will get the conjugate exponent, and if you assume that $\phi(x)$ is real then the conjugate of the whole Fourier transform will just be this minus sign in the exponent.

Comment: I do have an issue here however, just because two integrals are equal **does not** mean that the integrands are also equal. Why can you assume here that they are given that we showed the two integrals are equal only for the specific bounds $(-\infty,\infty)$ and not for any bounds ?

Comment: First of all, you don't need any such statement. You just need to work with the definition of fourier transform which give you $\phi(k)$. Now it seems like you tried something more complex and I am not exactly sure what, but keep in mind that Fourier transform is invertible